# Как найти среднее значение форматируемого диапазона?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, как можно найти среднее значения последних десяти отзывов, одновременно вытягивая из ячеек первое число

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы что-то недоговариваете? *Форматируемый диапазон* (указано в заголовке) - это как к вопросу относится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(СРЗНАЧ(ЗНАЧЕН(ПСТР(СМЕЩ(Output!D2;0;0;1;10);1;1))))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]